# Use theme-resources in keycloak storage SPI to extend admin theme

Tags: templates, jboss, wildfly, keycloak, service-provider

I'm using the [User Storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi) to add custom user federation to Keycloak. When my configuration shows up in the admin console, I would like to override some parts of the theme. This is the `admin` theme.

In the Keycloak Authenticator SPI, you can add custom stuff under `main/resources/theme-resources/messages` (or `/templates` or `/resources`). As long as your jar file has a `theme-resources` folder it will be picked up by Keycloaks `ClasspathThemeResourceProviderFactory`.

I'm struggling to make the same logic work for the storage provider.

Here's what I've tried: As a simple example, I am trying to override a message. I've setup `src/main/resources/theme-resources/messages/messages/messages_en.properties` with one line entry of `edit-mode.tooltip=HAM WAS HERE`. I've also setup `admin-messages_en.properties` with the same content (I'm not yet sure which is loaded). This message key `edit-mode.tooltip` is defined in the keycloak source file `themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/messages/admin-messages_en.properties`. When I load my SPI jar, I still see the message defined in the keycloak source, not the message defined by my jar.

Comment: I'm afraid that this approach is not working for admin themes. But you always can customize and deploy themes as standalone unit (In my team  we used this approach for building our custom themes for login pages and for emails from scratch). Check out this documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes.

Comment: Sadly that seems correct. I've opened https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18271 as a request for more flexibility in rendering the admin console

Comment: Also note that during implementation of custom User Storage Provider you can define user controls (like checkboxes, inputs, selectors) that will be shown in Storage Provider configuration panel. Check out usage of https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/provider/ProviderConfigurationBuilder.java

Comment: Yep thanks. I need much more complex controls, similar to how the LDAP provider uses accordion views and tabs